# Using Rack::Static, no Content-Type header is sent

Tags: ruby, http, content-type, rack

I'm using `Rack::Static` (or `Rack::TryStatic`) to serve some static HTML, Javascript, CSS and image files as part of a Rack application, but I see that the files served by Rack::Static do not have a Content-Type header, which causes warnings in some use cases and actually breaks the behavior of other use cases.

All the files have correct extensions, but the Content-Type header is actually missing from the HTTP response. I'm running Rack using Rackup which starts a WEBRick server.

How can I get Rack::Static to set up the correct content-type when sending files?

Comment: `Rack::Static` should be setting the content-type. Is the header missing altogether or is it present but wrong (e.g. `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream`)? Do the files themselves have extensions (so Rack can determine the type)?

Comment: I've updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I just had this same problem and I hoped that the solution might help someone. Try this:

```
use Rack::Static, urls: {'/my-doc' => '/public/my-doc'},
                  header_rules: [
                      ['/public/my-doc', {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}]
                  ]
```